# SQL State error relating to unknown column in Magento DB

Tags: php, sql, database, magento

We are trying to create page that shows all products from our website that contain a particular attribute, setting a filter on really. In this instance, any that are on sale. Currently generating an error below:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:90:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.special_price' in 'where clause'";i:1;s:5558:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT FLOOR((R...', Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT FLOOR((R...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(808): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Price.php(274): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchPairs(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php(158): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Price->getCount(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price), 10000)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php(115): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->getRangeItemCounts(10000)
#9 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Price.php(314): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->getPriceRange()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(151): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price->_getItemsData()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(120): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->_initItems()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(109): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItems()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/default/blanco/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml(13): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#16 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#17 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#18 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#21 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#23 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/default/blanco/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(20): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#24 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#25 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#26 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#27 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#28 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#29 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#30 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/community/Thirty4/CatalogSale/controllers/IndexController.php(9): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#31 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Thirty4_CatalogSale_IndexController->indexAction()
#32 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#33 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/community/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(234): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#34 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#35 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#36 /var/www/vhosts/domain/httpdocs/index.php(96): Mage::run('default')
#37 {main}";s:3:"url";s:49:"/sale.html?dir=asc&limit=60&mode=list&order=price";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

The code does work in a clean install of Magento. So points me towards thinking it might be a DB index or field named wrongly?

Comment: Check if any attribute has some model associated `attribute_model` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Attribute Model',
  `backend_model` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Backend Model',
   `frontend_model` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Frontend Model', As these gets fired when an attribute is fetched and these models might be needing that field.

Comment: The error is related to the special_price attribute, but query here is to work out which Magento DB table contains the error. Shy of checking every single table header and index that is used to create/store product detail. See what I mean?

Comment: In eav_attribute table check for frontend model,attribute model and backend model. Its basically these model entries that are not removed whena module is removed and these generate such bugs

Comment: @Blair Did you manage to find solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do this:

Admin > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend > Use Flat Catalog Product to "No"

Since this filtering is not compatible with the use of "Flat Catalog Product"